# Weird pop-up Alert on Monterey "“AdditionalLookupDaemon” will damage your computer."

Tags: macos, security, monterey

I just upgraded my mac from High Sierra to Monterey. And there are a lot of warning popups after the first launch. I try to solve them one by one, but I have no idea about this:
[image: the image of the popup](“AdditionalLookupDaemon” will damage your computer.)

At first, I click the "show in Finder", it bring me to folder which have a file call "AdditionalLookup". I drop it to the bin then empty it...... then this window popup again, again and again,  It didn't do anything either I click "OK" or "Show in Finder".
So I try to use the First Aid in the Dis Utility, Restarting... None of them worked.
[image]
The most important things is that it stuck my process of verifying, permission request from app. I need to click "OK"
or "Show in Finder" to 'Update' them... So weird.
Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Which is the folder where `AdditionalLookup` is located? What is the model of your Mac?

Comment: @jaume I'm using Version 12.3.1 (21E258) and the `AdditionalLookup` in the 
`Macintosh HD > Users > {my user name} > Library >  Application Support> com.AdditionalLookup > AdditionalLookup` 

*( I found another in `Macintosh HD > Library >  Application Support > com.AdditionalLookupDaemon > AdditionalLookup` and I also deleted it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after I delete all the `AdditionalLookup`, It didn't work immediately. But on the next day I turn on computer, this popup didn't show.

So if you get this problem too, you may need to delete all that file, shut down and wait...